# When using the react-calendly package can I grab the users input data (name and email) for tracking?

Tags: reactjs, calendly

I'm trying to implement a calendly widget in my webpage. I'm using the react-calendly NPM package and the implementation is simple but I would like to grab the name and email address that the user puts into the widget for tracking purposes. Is that data available to my application, and if so do you know how I get it? Please don't crucify me, this is my first ever post. :)

```
import { InlineWidget } from 'react-calendly';

const App = () => {
return <InlineWidget url="yourcalendlyurl"/>
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get this information into your application would be to create a webhook subscription with Calendly's v2 api (see [here](https://developer.calendly.com/api-docs/c1ddc06ce1f1b-create-webhook-subscription)).

When a Calendly event is scheduled a POST request will be sent to your server that includes the invitee's information - https://developer.calendly.com/api-docs/c2NoOjI3ODE4MDgw-webhook-payload